# The relationship between "orange" the colour and "orange" the fruit

Tags: etymology, semantics, cross-linguistic, colour-terms

This is something that bugged me before I studied linguists, and it still does - why is the word "orange" so often used for both the colour and the fruit cross-linguistically? Every language I've learned has these items as the same word, or at least very similar origins. English (*orange*), Polish (*pomarańczowy*), Italian (*arancione/arancia*) and Nepali (*suntala*). Granted, these are all Indo-European languages but they do cover quite a spread, and my sister tells me that Mandarin has the same feature with *chéng* referring to both the fruit and the colour. I'm assuming that languages have borrowed the work for the colour on the basis of the fruit, and not the other way around but I may be wrong.

I know that oranges are a relatively recently introduced fruit to many places, but is this phenomenon as cross-linguistically common as it appears from my limited experience. And if so, why?

Comment: Just for the record: although in Portuguese the color is most commonly called "laranja" (orange), in some dialects it is also known as "cor-de-abóbora" (pumpkin color).

Comment: @hLaureng. Just for the record, this question has already been [asked on EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28388/etymology-of-the-color-name-orange).

Comment: @AlainPannetier - thanks! I didn't think of looking there because my question wasn't just English specific, but your answer there is great. Would you mind bringing your answer across here as well for everyone else to read?

Comment: oh, and @OtavioMacedo I really like that example - I've never figured out why more languages didn't use other rather orange things like pumpkin or marigolds as sources, but at least some Portuguese speakers appear to!

Comment: Are we going to end up with one question for every single word in every single language? *eep*

Comment: I don't think so - most word origins are sufficiently understandable with a bit of dictionary digging, it's just that this appeared to be a rather consistent pattern cross-linguistically and until I read Alain's answer no one had really given what I thought was a sufficient explanation of that.

Comment: @kaleissin. I know quite a few people who would be elated to know "every single word in every single language", as you put it - me included.  Most of us are all too aware that this is unrealistic of course, but that doesn't stop us trying.  The only excuse I can invoke is the frequency of this syndrome among would-be linguists as well as real ones like William Jones, Champollion, the Grimm brothers and many more.

Comment: @LaurenG. I've imported and amended my ELU answer here. Please feel free to correct the phrasing and the syntax. I suspect it is still a little bit "rough".

Comment: @LaurenG - In Hindi (India) _orange color_ is called _Narangi_ and the fruit _Santra_ (i.e., they're different). However, purple doesn't have a word and its color is referred to as _Baingani_ (_like that of a Baingan_) after the Hindi name for Eggplant _Baingan_ - If linguistically a word for color isn't available it's "borrowed" from the closest _object_ AFAIK. But if a color doesn't exist we may have a word but no way to imagine (e.g. colorless).

Comment: @LaurenG My guess is that oranges have a fairly consistent hue compared to pumpkin & marigolds. Also, "gold" seems to come before "orange" as a basic color term. To me this shows the exotic nature of both the fruit and color at the time the word was being established. That is, it was different enough from a color speakers already had reason to talk about to be given a new color term. The same can be said for, say lilac.

Comment: Well *orange* (the fruit) has the color *orange* (the color). That's one way in how they are related.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In a situation where you want to refer to a colour and either you don't know of any name for that colour or you know the name but you also believe your interlocutor doesn't know it - you'll instinctively resort to the evocation of an object characterised by that colour.

The same holds true for other senses by the way. Would you rather say for instance "there's a smell of rotten egg" or "there's a smell of hydrogen sulfide"?

So, unless one wants to tell the policeman "I think the light was still in the 580-620 nm range when I crossed!", we need aliases for colours.

As for the *orange* colour, interestingly enough, the Old English word was "geoluread" (PDE yellow-red, G. gelb-rot). One has to say that in those times, very few people in England had had a chance of seeing real oranges.

The fact that oranges are quite alone in their category of orange-coloured objects added to their simple shape and the consistency of their shade probably explains why people commonly used it as a reference for the colour and that the name of the fruit became the name of the colour.

One can only notice that the phenomenon is a widespread one, observed in many languages and suffering only a few notable albeit easily understandable exceptions.

Here is a whirlwind tour of the various family of names for the fruit and its distinctive colour.

1. The first family is the Anglo French *Orange* and all its cognates

   - Italian: **arancia** (fruit) => **arancione** (colour).
   - Spanish: **naranja** (fruit) => **naranja** (colour).
   - Portuguese: **laranja** (fruit) => **[cor de] laranja** (colour).
2. In Europe, the *sweet* orange was first grown in Portugal in the 15th century<sup>**1**</sup> so that the fruit has a different name all around the mediteranean:

   - Greek: **πορτοκάλι** "portocâli" (fruit) => **πορτοκαλί** (colour).
   - Rumanian: **portocală** (fruit) => **portocaliu** (colour).
   - Arabic: the common word (for the sweet Orange is)  برتقال, **burtuqāl** (the persian  نارنج, nāranğ is only used for the bitter varety).  The colour name is identical **burtuqāl**.
   - Napolitan: **purtuall**<sup>**2**</sup>. AFAIR the colour name is identical.
   - Turkish: **portakal** but the colour is **turuncu** [from Persian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%AC%DB%8C) **nârenji** (نارنجی) => The bitter variety.
   - Persian: **porteqâl** (پرتقال) (meaning [both sweet orange and Portugal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84)) and **nârenji** (نارنجی) meaning both the colour and the bitter variety.
3. In Chinese, the colour (chéngsè **橙色**, *lit.* orange-colour) is named after the fruit (chéngzi **橙子**, *lit.* orange+[substantive marker]).

**Exceptions**

1. One notable exception is the common case of many northern countries in which the fruit has two concurrent names. an older one taken from *Old Dutch* **appelsien**<sup>**3**</sup>  now sinaasappel and a newer one taken from English *orange*.  In which case the colour itself is most of the time a cognate of *orange*.

   - Northern German: **Apfelsine**, and also Apfelsinenbaum, Apfelsinensaft. colour: **orange**.
   - Danish and Norwegian : **appelsin** => Appelsinjuice; colour: **Orange/Oransje**
   - Icelandic: **Appelsína**; colour **appelsínugulur** (orange-yellow).
   - more to the east: Russian: **апелсин**; and the colour: **oранжевый**.
2. In Dominican Republic, the orange colour is actually called "[mamey](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamey)" after the local fruit named [Mammee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammee_apple).  One has to mention though that they *do* have oranges over there but these are actually green.  The Mammey instead is... orange.  QED.

---

**Note 1**
<sup>[German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_%28Frucht%29):

Während die Bitterorange spätestens im 11. Jahrhundert nach Italien gekommen ist, wurde die süße Variante erst im 15. Jahrhundert nach Europa eingeführt, wo sie zunächst fast ausschließlich in Portugal angebaut wurde.</sup>
<sup>**Translation:** Although the bitter variety was already known in Italy by the 11th Century at the latest, the sweet variety was not introduced into Europe until the 15th Century, where it was first grown almost exclusively in Portugal.</sup>

**Note 2**
<sup>Napolitan people will tell you that it comes from French "Pour toi" but that's folk etymology</sup>

**Note 3**
<sup>appelsien = Chinese Apple. There is no relation with the original sin although many German contemporary oil paintings depict Adam and Eve together with the snake coiled inside an orange tree.</sup>

Comment: Nice answer, but are you sure "橙色" is the fruit? 色 in chinese means "color" basically. The Chinese name for orange is 橙子, the reading is *chéng **zi*** (not chéng sè) which why I think you mixed it. Tangerines, similarly, are called 桔子, read as *Júzi*.

Comment: @Alenanno. Absolutely right. Thank you. BTW I'd like to share a foolish idea about the etymology of this character. The left part is obviously the 木 "mù" radical (tree) and the right part is 登 "dēng" which means "to ascend". Now if you look at the [oldest recorded versions](http://www.chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?submitButton1=Etymology&characterInput=%E7%99%BB) of this character. You can see a man climbing up a ladder to pick fruit.  Even on today's character you can clearly see the two hands on the top.

Comment: Is that an established etymology? It's very interesting anyway! Thanks for sharing it :) P.S. I edited your answer, corrected the links and some formatting. :)

Comment: @Alain: No, 登 is merely a phonetic. The distance between 登 and 橙 isn't much.

Comment: @Alenanno, thank you so much for your editing.  "Is that an established etymology?". No it's, as I said, a "foolish idea" and @ Zhen Lin just confirmed that.  Axel Schuessler's "ABC  Etymological Dictionary of Old Chinese" (p. 208) at the 登 "dēng" entry has **'to ripen'** [Meng]" where Meng stands for [孟子 mèngzǐ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mencius).  Take a look at [B01843](http://www.chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?submitButton1=Etymology&characterInput=%E7%99%BB).

Comment: As far as I know, the Mongolian word for the fruit is "жүрж" (dshurdsh). And it is different from the color.

Comment: In Russian it's апельсин, not апелсин

Comment: The Dutch word is "oranje" and has been borrowed from French, not English. Dutch has had many loans from French, just like English has.

Comment: Just a minor correction, orange (the colour) in Arabic is burtuqāli, while the fruit is burtuqāl. Your point still stands though.

Comment: You might include information relevant to this quote from Wikipedia: "The word ultimately derives from a Dravidian language — possibly Tamil நாரம் nāram or Telugu నారింజ nāriṃja or Malayalam നാരങ്ങ‌ nāraŋŋa — via Sanskrit नारङ्ग nāraṅgaḥ "orange tree". From there the word entered Persian نارنگ nārang and then Arabic نارنج nāranj." Of notable interest is the loss of the leading "n" which is the equivalent of shifting from "a norange" to "an orange."

Answer (score 16):

I think hippietrail is on the right track.  Two things are worth mentioning:

- a [famous study by Berlin and Kay](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Basic_Color_Terms%3a_Their_Universality_and_Evolution) on the subject of color term hierarchies in language (e.g. if a language has a word for "blue" it must also have a term for "red," whereas the reverse does not hold).  Lots of follow-up research has been done on this subject.  "Orange" is relatively high on the hierarchy, i.e. according to the theory a language must already have a lot of other color terms before it can develop a word for "orange."
- The English word "pink" comes from the name of a flower (also "pink").  Many other IE languages have a word derived from "rose" for this color.  Irish has "white-red," though (no idea if this is a neologism).  "Pink" is also high on the Berlin & Kay hierarchy.

Comment: Interestingly, the terms for "brown," "pink," and "gold" will come before "orange" despite orange being considered a "secondary color."

Answer (score 12):

This relationship is called **polysemy**: when one meaning tends to be so close to another meaning that the word for one is generally co-opted as the word for another.

One of the most reliable examples of polysemy is container polysemy. The idea is that a container is so closely associated with its contents that we can use the term for the container to refer to its contents. Here's a minimal pair:

1. I broke the bottle of wine.
2. I drank the bottle of wine.

(Only the glass container can be the object of *break*; only the liquid inside can be the object of *drink*.)

Comment: I personally find how we talk about automobiles interesting. "That guy almost hit me!" actually means, "that guy almost hit my car with his car!" This suggests we expand our conception of conscious behavior (our own and other people's) to the those containers which we control from the inside.

Answer (score 6):

Alain Pannetier answers this pretty comprehensively, but there are some other notable exceptions where the word for the colour "orange" is cognate to neither *orange*, *Portugal*, nor *appelsien*:

#### Other fruits

- `Arabic` تُـرُنْج‎ (*turunj*) / `Persian` ترنج‎ (*toranj*) ["citron"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Citrus_medica)

  - `Catalan` taronja
  - `Turkish` turuncu
- [`Arabic` لَيْمُون‎ (*laymūn*) , `Persian` لیمو‎ (*limu*)](https://archive.org/stream/dictionaryofhaus01robiuoft#page/232/mode/2up/search/lemo)

  - `Hausa` lemu, lemo "lime, lemon"
- `Armenian` գազար "carrot"

  - `Armenian` գազարագույն (*gazaraguyn*)
- `Catalan` carabassa, carbassa "pumpkin" `(Valencia)`
- `Portuguese` abóbora "pumpkin"
- `Spanish` mamey ["mammee"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammea_americana) `(Dom. Rep.)`
- `Hebrew` כתום (*katom*) <sub>(the fruit is called תפוז (*tapooz*) abbreviation of *tapuach* + *zahav*, “golden apple”)</sub>

#### "red" + yellow

- `Welsh` melyngoch < *melyn* (“yellow”) +‎ *coch* (“red”)
- `Cornish` rudhvelyn < *rudh* ("red") +‎ *melyn* ("yellow")
- `Faroese` brandgulur < *brandur* (“fire”) +‎ *gulur* ("yellow")
- `Irish` flannbhuí < *flann* (“blood-red”) +‎ *buí* ("yellow")

#### Misc.

- `Ancient Greek`  σανδαράκινος (*sandaràkinos*) "the color of the legs of birds"

---

#### The word for the fruit "orange" in the languages of Europe:

[image]

#### The spread of the word for the fruit "orange":

[image]

[**Errata:**](https://www.reddit.com/r/etymologymaps/comments/7kyo3d/spread_of_the_word_for_orange_963733/)

- In German *Pomeranze* refers to the bitter/Seville orange. *Orange/Apfelsine* is orange.
- Norwegian *oransje* is the colour; *appelsin* is the fruit.

Comment: Excellent addendum! Far underrated

Answer (score 4):

I believe that orange is not just a recently introduced fruit in many parts but that the concept of a colour word for this shade is also recent.

Recall that many languages do just fine with much fewer colour words than English has.

In some languages "orange" doesn't always have full status as a normal adjective but may sometimes be a circumlocution like "orange colour" or "colour of orange".

Comment: Yes, I know that orange is rather far down the list of colours that are found in a language (on something like a Berlin and Kay analysis) - but I never figured out why they all found inspiration in the same foodstuff.

Comment: Well when you try to think of common orange things, especially non-modern or fairly universal things it's hard to come up with much. For instance where I grew up the typical colour for pumpkins is green (-:

Comment: If the word would have to be coined in modern Berlin, it would relate to waste collection (and street cleaning), as the color of their cars and clothes is orange :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment to the OP, so I will give you this information in an "answer". In Hebrew the fruit "orange" is a new idea, and thus has a new word. However, instead of calling it by the colour orange (which would be כתום "Katom" in Hebrew) we call it a תפוז "tapuz" which is a portmanteau of "golden apple". So the fruit is in fact named after a colour, but not the colour of it's peel.

Comment: Do you know where "כתום" comes from? Is it an ancient Hebrew word or did Ben Jehuda devise it?

Comment: @hippietrail: I've searched but not found good information on the etymology of the word כתום for the colour in Hebrew. The Wikipedia page for the colour has some obviously-incorrect conclusions about the etymology drawn from Arabic and English. It states that the root of the word means, among other things, "gold", though today it means only "stain". The "gold" meaning may not be verifiable, even if it is a word from the bible. Greek has a similar problem with the colour "blue", which so far as we know, is not referenced in ancient Greek literature.

Answer (score 2):

In Malayalam, the color is now said **orange** (loan from English):

ഓറഞ്ച്(നിറം)
oorañčə(niram)
[ˈoːrɐɲdʒɐ(ˈnɪrɐm)]

:( The fruit is said orange too: ഓറഞ്ച്

As for pink, there's a choice between

ഇളംചുവപ്പ്        iLamčuvappə  [ˈiɭɐmˈtʃʊʋɐppə] (light-red)
and the English loan:

പിങ്ക്(നിറം)     pinkə(niram) [ˈpiŋkə(ˈnɪrɐm)]

Unfortunately, most of these ''new'' colors and shades in Indian languages are just borrowed directly from English, even in mainstream Tamil (which is known for its purism).

Comment: Interesting. I read that the Western term derives from the Dravidian. Wikipedia: "The word ultimately derives from a Dravidian language — possibly Tamil நாரம் nāram or Telugu నారింజ nāriṃja or Malayalam നാരങ്ങ‌ nāraŋŋa — via Sanskrit नारङ्ग nāraṅgaḥ "orange tree". From there the word entered Persian نارنگ nārang and then Arabic نارنج nāranj"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tom Sugnetic.
Even though the color names in Tamil are borrowed from English, there was/still is an attempt to create new words by using Tamil roots.
Name for each new color is formed by combining the names of the basic colors which form it. Generally, (veLLai) white and (kaRuppu) black are used to show the intensity/brightness of the new color.

For example, orange is called as "whitish red". (வெண்சிவப்பு in Tamil).

Dark blue is called as "blackish blue" (கருநீலம்).

Pink is called as "younger red" (இளஞ்சிவப்பு).

Around 100 new names have been invented for colors in Tamil.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another language that I don't think has been mentioned yet. The Bengali (or Bangla) word for both the fruit and the color is কমলা (transliteration: komola).

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE! We need more specific answers and this one just adds another language. Please add more detail for this answer.